# Extensions on WebView2 on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, browser, webview2

I would like to use AdBlock extension in WebView2. How can i add extensions to WebView2?

I have searched and found out that WebView currently doesnt support extensions. If there is some play around then let me know please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebView2 doesn't currently support browser extensions (see the [Differences between WebView2 and the browser doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/browser-features#:%7E:text=is%20turned%20off.-,Browser%20Extensions,-Off) which notes its not currently supported).

There is work in progress to add support for browser extensions (you can see the [draft API spec for browser extension APIs](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/pull/3409/files)) but there is currently no expected date for when such a feature will be added.